# Foul or fair softball

Tags: rules, softball

A batted ball hits fair between home and third, bounces into the air and is caught while over foul territory in the air without ever touching foul territory and the player that caught it is in fair territory.

Answer (score 0):

For MLB rules (which I'm assuming are used unless otherwise stated), and the ball has not yet passed third base, the the only thing that matters is where the ball is first touched.

In the stated scenario, the ball is first touched (caught) in foul territory.  The fact the defense is standing in fair territory, or that the ball last bounced in fair territory do not matter.

From [MLB Rules 2019](https://img.mlbstatic.com/mlb-images/image/upload/mlb/ttajxpedgemiy4sx0cer.pdf)

> A FOUL BALL is a batted ball that settles on foul territory between
>   home and first base, or between home and third base, or that bounds
>   past first or third base on or over foul territory, or that first
>   falls on foul territory beyond first or third base, or that, **while on
>   or over foul territory, touches the person of an umpire or player**, or
>   any object foreign to the natural ground.

Having touched the player while over foul territory, this is a foul ball.

[NCAA Softball rules](http://www.ncaapublications.com/productdownloads/SR19.pdf) reuse this statement as rule 11.5.1.4

A foul ball is a legally batted ball that ...

> 11.5.1.4 Settles untouched on, or **first touches/is touched by (1) a fielder or umpire**, (2) either of their attached equipment or clothing,
>   (3) accidentally by a base runner or her equipment/clothing, or (4)
>   any object foreign to the natural playing surface **on or over foul
>   territory between home plate and first base or home plate and third
>   base**, **even if the batted ball** first rolled against the discarded bat
>   (see Rule 11.12.1) or **hit the ground in fair territory including the
>   pitcher’s plate and home plate**.

Comment: Why mention MLB rules at all when the question is clearly about softball only?

Comment: Because they are readily available and a great many rules are identical between baseball and softball.   The question didn't specify the league, so the NCAA softball rules may be no more relevant than MLB.

Comment: NCAA softball rules are at least softball rules, and acceptable as one alternative, just as we accept answers based on both NBA and FIBA rules when a question is about "basketball" unspecified. MLB is however definitely not softball, regardless of how many rules may be similar or even identical.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect.  The ball needs to touch foul territory to be called foul.  And is why an Umpire does not declare a foul ball until it has made contact with the ground, a player (un-caught) in foul territory, or the fence.  Otherwise a catch could not be made in foul territory, as we see in MLB nearly daily.

A batted ball between home and 1st / home and 3rd, bouncing from fair ground into foul territory, caught before:

- it touches foul territory,
- careenes off a player in foul territory,
- or the fence,

is a fair ball, as it has not yet reached foul territory.

Otherwise, no ball could be caught in foul territory...

Comment: This answer appears to be applying baseball, particularly MLB rules, but the question is about softball. Can you clarify the relevance of MLB rules or provide a softball reference?

Comment: Why did you add "un-caught" in parenthesis?  That's not in the rules that I see.   Balls are caught in foul territory all the time. I don't understand the argument that such a definition would prevent catches there.